# Losing CSS when redirecting with .htacess

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am having trouble keeping my css when redirecting one page to another using .htaccess. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dev.elearning.batraining.com/$1 [R,L]
Redirect 301 /theme/batheme/loginPage/login.php https://dev.elearning.batraining.com/login/index.php
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your css files are loading with `link` tag pay attention that the path to the css file is absolute with or without domain.

- Fully absolute path- `http://www.my-site.com/path/to/css`
- Absolute path- `/path/to/css`

Otherwise your css files will be loaded relative to the "rewrite" path (and usually it not match real folder structure).